# Flutter - can't download file (package Flutter Downloader)

Tags: flutter

Using package flutter_downloader: ^1.3.4
After pressing button, notification is shown, but file does not being saved on device
All permissions are given, no errors or mistakes whatsoever

Comment: did you find any solution please? because i have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

*Please **Remove** this code from Androidmanifest.xml*

```
<provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
  </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following changes

in pubspac.yml

```
flutter_downloader: ^1.3.3
```

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml inside application Tag

```
<provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
         android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
         android:value="androidx.startup"
         tools:node="remove" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>

<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:exported="false" />

<provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
        android:value="5" />
</provider>
```

Comment: it say's: "WorkManager is already initialized", what to do?

Comment: @RahulZx You need to disable default initializer first.